# Computing information content in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, entropy, information-theory

I need to compute information content from two Python lists. I understand that I can use the following formula where the probabilities are computed from the histograms of the list.

Information content = sum_ij p(x_i,y_j) log_2 ( p(x_i,y_j)/(p(x_i)p(y_j) )  / - sum_i p(y_i) log_2 p(y_i) .

Is there any built in Python API to compute information content? Thanks.

Comment: Has your question been answered, or do you have a clarification?

Comment: @aryamccarthy my lists contain real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `information_content` function in the `biopython` library: http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc303